# SQL join with where beforehand join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

what would be the correct way of doing this so SQL doesn't produce syntax error?

I do have the following (it does work):

```
SELECT *
FROM table.track
JOIN table.album
ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId;
```

What I look for:

```
SELECT *
FROM table.track WHERE Name LIKE 'something'
JOIN table.album
ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId;
```

I know it's probably easy, but I can't get the syntax to work...

Comment: The `WHERE` clause follows the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the where clause must be place after the join clause

```
    SELECT *
    FROM track
    JOIN album
    ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId
    WHERE track.Name LIKE 'something'
```

and if you need some wildchar

```
    SELECT *
    FROM track
    JOIN album
    ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId
    WHERE track.Name LIKE '%something%'
```

Comment: Thanks... as easy as thought, exactly what I needed!